# How to modify an extra field in response model to differentiate if an item belongs to a user depending on the ORM objects

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I want to have an extra field in my response depending on the user id.

The project is a mini ecommerce app where only the shop owner can edit its content. When the frontend requests GetAllShops,

how can I attach a boolean field like **is_owner** for every shop entity returned from sql alchemy ORM by comparing the id of the shop with the id of the client?

I'm using Pydantic and FastAPI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can populate the field before returning it yourself by looping through the returned ORM objects, creating the pydantic objects manually (`ModelName.from_orm(..)`) and setting it with the appropriate value?

Comment: @MatsLindh, would you please share the full code for adding is_owner field? I'm pretty new in Pydantic. Thank so much. Or should I store user id in client side to compare and decide which item belongs to the user? Which approach do you think would be better?

Comment: `shops_with_is_owner = [], for shop in shops: shop_with_is_owner = ShopWithIsOwner.from_orm(shop), shop_with_is_owner.is_owner = current_user.id == shop.owner_user_id, return shops_with_owner` - something like that; test if it works for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a root validator, which is the most powerful method:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    client_id: str
    shop_id: str
    is_owner: bool = False

    # Root validators are executed during model instantiation
    # before values are assigned
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def check_if_owner(cls, values: dict):
        
        if values['client_id'] == values['shop_id']:
            values['is_owner'] = True

        # All done
        return values
```

Another more nuanced solution is to use a regular validator with accessing all class values. This is similar to above, but specific for just this field. (Note: This method can get pretty complex and hairy, so proceed with caution.)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    client_id: str
    shop_id: str
    is_owner: bool = False


    @validator('is_owner', always=True)
    def check_if_owner(cls, value, values: dict):
        
        if values['client_id'] == values['shop_id']:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```